# Laravel Docker Unable to insert data

Tags: laravel, docker

I was learning docker and was able to run `docker-compose` on production. Below is my production file

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    container_name: myapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Fpm.Production.Dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www/html/dockerapps/laravel-docker-boilerplate
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html/dockerapps/laravel-docker-boilerplate
    links:
      - db
    networks:
      - mynet
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: db
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laraapp
      MYSQL_USER: laraveluser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: laravel
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
    networks:
      - mynet
#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
#Docker Networks
networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
```

DB config in .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laraapp
DB_USERNAME=laraveluser
DB_PASSWORD=laravel
```

**Migration is running successfully** but when I try to create new user I am facing this below error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No address associated with hostname (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = user@gmail.com)
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Output of `docker ps` command

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                            COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                 NAMES
a2ad106d6cd4        laravel-docker-boilerplate_app   "docker-php-entrypoi…"   21 minutes ago      Up 21 minutes       9000/tcp              myapp
b45032551712        mysql:5.7                        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   21 minutes ago      Up 21 minutes       3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   db
```

Comment: Can you show `docker ps` logs? I think we should add an depend_on db options for app

Comment: @TruongDang Post updated. When I try to print DB_HOST in blade by {{ env("DB_HOST") }} it's showing empty!

Comment: So just simply run `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: Now showing the DB_HOST name as db(container name) but still not able to insert.

Comment: can you run echo DB_HOST in tinker?

Comment: docker-compose exec app php artisan tinker and tried env("DB_HOST") and showing DB_HOST name "db"

Comment: So can you connect db yet?

Comment: `php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No address associated with hostname` still facing this error when tried to insert into DB

Comment: can you run `docker network ls` and check that `mynet` are created. Then check `docker network inspect` and make sure both app and db container join in `mynet `?

Comment: Here is the output https://imgur.com/a/9XtZoAv

Comment: I think that's because you haven't expose the mysql port to out.
`ports:
      - 3306:3306`

Comment: If I add this port, I face issue of same port already in use.

Comment: How are you running the migration?

Comment: Check if you have another database service running on the server that's using this port.